# WP archives order by custom meta key

Tags: php, wordpress

in Wordpress template's *function.php* following code is working well

```
// Function accepting current query
function my_change_order( $query ) {
    // Check if the query is for an archive
    if($query->is_archive())
        // Query was for archive, then set order
        $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
    // Return the query (else there's no more query, oops!)
    return $query;
}
// Runs before the posts are fetched
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );
```

But i need to order articles by custom meta key like `_my_meta_vip`. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146241/1589669) i tried following lines, with half success, because only load articles with defined custom meta key, others are missing. How can i solve that?

```
function my_change_order( $query ) {
    if($query->is_archive())
        $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key' , '_my_meta_vip' );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );
```

How can i order my articles by custom meta key properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally can't find any way to list all post with and without `_my_meta_VIP` defined.

In my solution all `_my_meta_VIP` was filled with `enabled` or `disabled` and the following code do the job:

```
    // Function accepting current query
    function my_change_order( $query ) {
        // Check if the query is for an archive
        if($query->is_archive()) {
            // Query was for archive, then set order
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'profile' );
            $query->set( 'orderby' , 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key' , '_my_meta_vip' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        } else {
            // Return the original query for non-archive pages
            return $query;
        }
        // Return the query
        return $query;
    }
    // Runs before the posts are fetched
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   function my_change_order( $query ) {
        // Check if the query is for an archive
        if($query->is_archive())
        // Query was for archive, then set order
        $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
              'key' => '_my_meta_vip'
            )
        ));

        // Return the query (else there's no more query, oops!)
        return $query;
    }
```

look at the following topic: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20237/using-meta-query-how-can-i-filter-by-a-custom-field-and-order-by-another-one may give you a clear idea

Comment: i can't see the difference and doing the same as my code. :(

Comment: see meta_query is send is assign & send through array

Comment: still not showing posts without `_my_meta_vip` defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the underlying issue here is that the query is doing an inner join on the posts and postmeta tables, which is why posts that don't have that particular post meta entry aren't being returned by the query. What you want is a left join. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770366/difference-in-mysql-join-vs-left-join) for an explanation of the difference.

You should be able to use the `posts_join` filter to replace the inner join with a left join:

```
add_filter('posts_join', function($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Replace inner join with left join
    $search = 'INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta;
    $replace = 'LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta;
    $join = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $join);

    return $join;
});
```