# Wordpress Sort Posts by custom Meta Value Date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, meta

This is my code to query the posts but it doesnt work. I have a date format like this: dd.mm.yyyy

i changed the format a couple of times but it still dont work.

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'gestorben',
        'value' => date('dd.mm.yyyy'),
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
),
'post_type'        => 'traueranzeigen',
'showposts'        => 10,
'paged'            => $paged,
'suppress_filters' => $suppress_filters, 
    'meta_key' => 'gestorben', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => 'DSC'
);
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: I think You doesn't have `meta_query` please view this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145984/ordering-wp-posts-by-custom-meta-key

Answer (score 3):

thanks it works now

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'traueranzeigen',
    'showposts'        => 10,
    'paged'            => $paged,
    'suppress_filters' => $suppress_filters, 
    'meta_key'         => 'gestorben',
    'meta_type'        => 'DATETIME', 
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_datetime', 
    'order'            => 'ASC'
);
```