# Fetch WordPress posts and order by meta_key's ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to fetch the post by `meta_key` in WordPress, and now I want to order posts by the `meta_key`'s ID.

My code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'featured',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to order them based on the time `meta_key` was created. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Refer this https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: Welcome to StackOvelFlow , please improve your question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering WP Posts by Custom Meta Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145984/ordering-wp-posts-by-custom-meta-key)

Comment: @RaunakGupta please read my explanation better. 